# How to connect logic of application with UI?

Tags: java, database, user-interface, design-patterns

I have following problem. I wrote simple application that is working as a book store. I would like to write GUI for this app. I started wondering how shall I connect the GUI with logic of app.

I have a class DBManager that allows me to do some operations connected with data base: putting new entities, deleting tables, ect...
The first idea is to put the instance of DBManager in GUI class and than connect the buttons with methods of DBManager.

I generally think that the class that is responsible for GUI shall do the interaction with the User of application. and pass the information from user to the other class that shall be responsible for dealing with user request and giving the response for it to the GUI class that will show the result of request. Am I correct?

Comment: This question is far too broad for StackOverflow. You need to first determine what GUI framework you want to use (either Swing or JavaFX) and then look at some introductory tutorials.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I used swing once in the past. What is general difference between Swing and JavaFX?

Comment: There are vast differences, really. JavaFX is the replacement of the older Swing framework. I would recommend JavaFX over Swing as it is more powerful and arguably easier to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to figure out is what "**architectural pattern**" to use. In your case I suggest you to use the MVC pattern, which has three components: Model, View and Controller.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> Model:
>   The central component of the pattern. It is the application's dynamic data structure, independent of the user interface. It directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.
>
> View:
>   Any representation of information such as a chart, diagram or table. Multiple views of the same information are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for accountants.
>
> Controller: 
>   Accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view.

Another important thing to consider is the framework you want to use to build you application because it can impose you a pattern to use. Most used UI frameworks for building rich clients for Java are JavaFX and Swing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I red about MVC pattern. I guess I shall see some examples of implementation of it.

Comment: @Flood2d How would I implement an MVC approach in JavaFX? For example, whenever I use `GridPane`s, I store each `Node` in a separate 2D array so that I can access it later. That approach seems like a hack; how am I supposed to so it?

Comment: @ap GridPane is a container and lays out nodes in a grid. By nodes I mean other controls like Label and TextField. In your controller class you need a Node variable for each control you need to access. If you are not using FXML you probably already have these variables instantiated to create the UI. If you are using FXML then you need to bind them by using fx:id on each control and by creating the corresponding variables in the controller class. You should check the official documentation on how to use it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: @ap if you are using FXML then you can check this guide here https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm